# : this page isn't working. is unable to handle the request. Http error 500

Tags: errors, http

I recently started a WordPress travel website hosted on bluehost. Im a complete newbie to WordPress and bloggjng. I installed a plug in called one click child theme, and went to create a child theme. When I clicked on create child theme , it showed the error page: this page isn't working. Talesandmiles.com is. unable to handle the request. Http error 500.
From then, not able to sign into my site.
When I open my website URL in another window, my site is opening but showing an older version.

I searched on Google and tried following things:
Disabled all plugins.
Deleted the child theme folder.
Still the problem is not solved

Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you also cleared your browser's cache?

Comment: Hi, Yes but it did not work. I contacted blue host and they told the problem is with theme so they changed the theme to one of the default wordpress themes, and it worked after that.